# Add audio file and text file to same list item

Tags: document-library, document

I'm new to Sharepoint 2013. I've been given a task to add a library for audio files. There is also a text file associated with audio file. How can I add both files as a single item in a library/list in SharePoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Document sets for this requirement. You can create and management multi-document work products with the new Document Set content type. A Document Set is a group of related documents that can be created in one step and then managed as a single entity.

For more details:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/document-set-feature-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try using Document Set.I need to use workflow for the library too. Any idea if workflow can be implemented in Document Set in the same way as Document Library?

Comment: Yes you can add workflow to document set in the same way as in list-item. Check the following post: http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/sharepoint-2010-workflows-and-document-setsstart-the-workflow-when-a-new-item-is-createdbe-careful/

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting the contents of the text file into a field on the list item instead of attaching it? It would solve your requirement

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The text file contains the transcript of the audio files and the user wants it in document format.